# Amazon redshift or Athena/presto business day calculation between 2 days

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, presto

i have a calendar table but am not sure how to get business day subtraction to work using amazon redshift or amazon athena(presto). I have seen a few posts that mention to use a calendar but cant get it to work with redshift or athena. any help would be appreciated. This is what i have so far. its a subtraction between 2 different tables that i need in business days. thank you

```
table1.createddate (start date)
table2.createddate (end date)
cal.date (cal table, column 'date' is what i can inner join with)
cal.is_week_end is either yes or no on this table.
```

```
SELECT table1.id,
table1.createddate,
table2.NAME,
table2.createddate,
Datediff(day, table1.createddate, table2.createddate) AS age1
FROM   table2
LEFT JOIN table1
ON table2.id = table1.id2;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Thanks, ill try the answer below on Tuesday, if any issues. ill come with some sample data and desired result. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tables have ids to match them, then you can use a correlated subquery.  I think this will work:

```
select t1.*, t2.*,     -- whatever columns you want
       (select sum( (c.is_weekend = 'no')::int )
        from calendar c
        where c.date >= t1.createddate and
              c.date <= t2.createddate
       ) as num_nonweekend_days
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id;
```

If there is an issue with the correlation clause (which can sometimes happen), you can also use:

```
select t1.id,
       count(c.date) as num_nonweekend_days
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id left join
     calendar c
     on c.date >= t1.createddate and
        c.date <= t2.createddate and
        c.is_week_end = 'no'
group by t1.id;
```

If you want additional columns, you need to include them in the `select` and `group by`.